# How to find the size of a particular data in Android?

Tags: android

I want to find the size of the image(eg 512KB) and so on ,how to find it??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean from within android, you can use the built in Gallery for most android phones, just hit menu while viewing the picture, choose "More" and then the "Details" option which will show you all the information about the picture.

Otherwise you can try a free file explorer called "ES FILE EXPLORER" from the Android Market, then you can locate the file on your sd card for example and tap and hold to bring up some specific options for that file, if you scroll through the operations available you will find "Properties" at the bottom of the list which will show the size of the image.

Otherwise checkout 
[Size of Image in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367961/size-of-image-in-android)